# bash __git_ps1 command not found

Tags: macos, git, bash, ps1

I am a beginner trying to setup a developer environment on my new Mac following the steps from this link: http://vanderveer.be/setting-up-my-perfect-developer-environment-on-osx-10-8-mountain-lion-10-8-2-final-edition/.

After executing the files from git, my terminal window now shows:

```
rbenv: version `1.9.3-p194' not installed
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
```

The first line only shows when I open a new terminal window, while the second shows everytime I press return no matter what I type into the terminal.

I have read through many questions on stackoverflow and tried to mimic their solutions to no avail. I think I've made a mistake in installing the package from git as I am not so experienced and I think now I may have messed up the configurations, and was also wondering if there is any way to go back to default settings for bash?

Many thanks!
Allen

Comment: If you look at the comments of that link you pointed us to, you'll see [this illuminating comment:](http://vanderveer.be/setting-up-my-perfect-developer-environment-on-osx-10-8-mountain-lion-10-8-2-final-edition/#comment-904588335) "the __git_ps1 is when the git bash completion scripts are not available. Make sure you installed bash_completion and git".  There's additional useful comments on that page as well.

Comment: I did read those comments and tried their solutions to no avail, which is why I came to stackoverflow for help. Thanks!

Comment: What git version do you have? Do you have bash_completion installed (as in http://superuser.com/a/288491/141)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you've not installed a newer version of Git on your Mac, start by doing that.  You can grab the download from here: http://git-scm.com/download

Once it's installed, you should source `git-completion.sh` and `git-prompt.sh` from your `~/.profile` (or ~/.bashrc, if you have it):

```
source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
```

That should fix the `__git_ps1` error.

I'm not a Rubyist, but the rbenv error is coming from the fact that the setup in the dotfiles you are following is trying to set the default Ruby version to "1.9.3-p194".  The rbenv tool is there to make a number of different Ruby versions available, but you have to install them first.  In your case, I think you need to run this:

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-p194
```

After that, the version will be available, and you shouldn't see the warning anymore.

Comment: `/usr/share/git/completion/` in my case (Arch)

Comment: `source /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt` to fix the `__git_ps1` incident in my case (git 2.7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04). The in-line comments in that file do suggest to copy it to a local directory and rename it `git-prompt.sh`